# How do I declare a list of types, and later instantiate one?

Tags: c#, class, list, types, reference

I have a case where I have some classes that each process a type of token.  They all descend from a base handler class (simplified down a bit, so excuse any anti-compile typos):

```
public abstract class TokenClassBase
{
  public static bool HandlesTokenType(TokenKind AType)
  {
    return handledTokens.Contains(AType);
  }
  protected virtual void HandleToken(AToken)
  {
  }
}

public class TokenClass1 : TokenClassBase
{
  public static new bool HandlesTokenType(TokenKind AKind)
  {
    return AKind == TokenKind.type1;
  }
  public override void HandleToken(AToken)
  {
  //do some work
  }

}
// public class TokenClass2... etc
```

I also have a worker class where I'd like to store a list of these handlers, and later instantiate one of the handlers to process a token:

```
public class MyWorker
{
  private List<Type> handlers;
  public MyWorker()
  {
    handlers = new List<Type>;
    handlers.Add(typeof(TokenClass1));
    handlers.Add(typeof(TokenClass2));
    //... etc
  }
  protected virtual void HandleToken(AToken)
  {
    foreach (TokenBaseClass handler in handlers)
    {
      if (handler.HandlesToken(AToken))
      {
        instantiate(handler);
        handler.HandleToken(AToken);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I handle the last foreach?  Is this even possible - or is there a better way?  I like the extensibility of being able to add new types in the future, just by adding them to the handlers list (or even passing them in from outside).
I'm using c#, framework 3.5+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible like this, no - because your list is a list of *types*, not references to *instances* of that type.

The closest you can easily come, assuming that there's a parameterless constructor for each type, is:

```
foreach (Type handlerType in handlers)
{
   // Create an instance of the handler type
   TokenBaseClass handler = 
       (TokenBaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
   if (handler.HandlesToken(AToken))
   {
     handler.HandleToken(AToken);
     break;
   }
}
```

EDIT: In answer to your question in the comments, I would handle this slightly differently.

I would change your `List<Type>` to a `List<Func<TokenKind, TokenClassBase>>`. In other words, a list of factory functions, from `TokenKind` to `TokenClassBase`. The function for each type would depend on the type, but it would *either* return an instance of `TokenClassBase`, *or* `null` if that `TokenKind` couldn't be handled.

Then you'd use:

```
foreach (var handlerFactory in handlerFactories)
{
    TokenBaseClass handler = handlerFactory(AToken);
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.HandleToken(AToken);
        break;
    }
}
```

The way that you'd create the delegates would depend on the exact nature of your code, but you could either use a lambda expression or a method group conversion, probably from a static method.

Comment: You can also have the handlers implement ICloneable (if you want to clone an instance per 'serivce request')

Comment: @sehe: Yes, but you'd still need to have a list of instances, rather than a list of types.

Comment: Aha, I misread your comment, and assumed that the types were already being stored by their instances. Reading too fast, sry. Still ICloneable rings on-topic here :)

Comment: Ah, the Activator.CreateInstance is what I was looking for to replace my 'instantiate(handler)' line.  Is there any way to call a static method (HandlesToken) in the class without doing this?  Essentially I want to ask, "can this class handle the task", before I instantiate it.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, this provides a good direction.  I'm a bit hazy on the last step of filling the handlerFactories list with a reference to a static method; do you mean I'd use 
handlerFactories.Add(TokenKind.type1, TokenClass1.HandleToken)
?

Comment: @Geoff: Just `handlerFactories.Add(TokenClass1.BuildHandler)` where `BuilderHandler` would be a method either creating an instance of `TokenClass1 or returning `null`.

Comment: @Jon: AH, ok!  Thanks - the light bulb just went on.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method.

Your loop would be

```
foreach (Type handlerType in handlers)
{
  if (...not sure how you'd do this part...)
  {
    TokenBaseClass handler = (TokenBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
    handler.HandleToken(AToken);
    break;
  }
}
```

For the missing piece, you'd basically need a list of what tokens each type can handle. If it's a 1-1 relationship, you might consider a `Dictionary<TokenKind,Type>`. Or, to avoid reflection entirely, use a `Dictionary<TokenKind,Func<TokenClassBase>>` and each value is `() => new TokenClass1()`.

Why do you want a list of types instead of a list of instances anyway?